# Execute a list of Unix commands using ssh

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to run the same set of Unix commands on multiple machines. I am aware of ssh and something like the below. I want to write a shell script to do this. I have access to bash and ksh and I'm on Linux Red Hat 5.

```
ssh root@ip "echo \$HOME"
```

However, I have 2 questions:

1. I keep getting prompted for a password. How can I have it not prompt me and enter the password automatically?
2. How can I execute multiple commands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You should use [key based authentification](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/530), possibly coupled with `ssh-agent` to remember key passphrase.
2. <strike>You can invoke `sh -c` as the command, and pass it a string containing the list of command to execute.</strike> `ssh` invoke a shell on the remote machine, so you can pass a list of command as a string.

For example:

```
$ ssh user@ip "echo 'Hello world'; whoami; cd / ; ls"
```

Comment: Thank you, this information looks helpful. However, even after generating a key on machine 1 and adding it to machine 2 as described in that link, I am still prompted for a password. Do you have any thoughts? Here is what I did:

1.) machine1: ssh-keygen
2.) machine1: ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa.pub user@ip

Comment: You now need to start up ssh-agent and use ssh-add to add it to your keychain to prevent future password prompting.

Comment: Please note, that you need to do that every time you login. You could also create a ssh key without passphrase, but be aware of the security implication (everybody who can get read access to the private key will be able to connect without password).

Comment: You don't need the `sh -c` part, ssh starts a shell anyway. In fact, do not use `sh -c`, as it requires yet another level of quoting (@Sylvain: your command doesn't work because you haven't put that extra level of quoting).

Answer (score 1):

Use ssh-agent to set up authentication for all commands. Or put your multiple commands into a single shell script.

Answer (score 0):

2. Send a list of commands to the remote shell. Possible solutions:

   - use `"`, escape line breaks to format code and end each substatement with `;`.
     Disadvantage: `"` should **not** be used inside the command list.

     ```
     ssh user@ip "\
       echo 'Hallo sir, how are you doing?';\
       whoami;\
       cd /;\
       ls\
     "
     ```
   - use `'` and format code with regular line breaks.
     Disadvantage: `'` should **not** be used inside the command list.

     ```
     ssh user@ip '
       echo "Hallo sir, how are you doing?"
       whoami
       cd /
       ls
     '
     ```

*Note*: using `"` or `'` inside the respective statements will not necessarily result in an error. Though you may get unsuspected results.